# change visibility with expression in Microsoft Report rdlc

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

i need to change the visibility of a image in my report. For that i'm using an expression.
For default i want it set to true, and when i'm printing i set the parameter to false so the image doen't show up. Problem is, image never show's up.

`=CBool(Parameters!ShowImage.Value)`

c# (the parameter i send when creating the report)

```
p[27] = new ReportParameter("ShowImage", "True");
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the **Hidden** property of the control in the RDLC right?

Try `=(Parameters!ShowImage.value="False")`

Comment: Does not work =(

right now i'm setting in tab visibility:

Expression: =CBool(Parameters!ShowImage.Value)

i tried =True, image doesn't show up either..

Comment: What does the RLDC file look like in XML?
you should see something like:
        <Visibility>
          <Hidden>=(Parameters!ShowImage.Value="False")</Hidden>
        </Visibility>

Comment: <Image Name="image1">
        <Sizing>Fit</Sizing>
        <Visibility>
          <Hidden>=CBool(Parameters!ShowImage.Value)</Hidden>
        </Visibility>

Comment: ok, i changed the xml to (Parameters!ShowImage.Value="False"). Now it shows the image (like i want). But when i print, it does not hide the image. How i'm doing it:

private void reportViewer1_Print(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            ReportParameter[] p = new ReportParameter[1];
            p[0] = new ReportParameter("ShowImage", "True");
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);

        }

Comment: hawbsl thanks for your help :)
 The main problem was that i was setting the parameter in the wrong place (i went to properties, visibility, expression).